# How to build a jQuery object out of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two distinct jQuery objects, one from a selector query and one created from html code. Now I want to make another jQuery object out of these to do operations on both of them.

As you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/D799Y/), it is possible to do this by using the "get" operation and building an array of elements:

```
var $first = $('div.first'),
    $overlay = $('<div class="overlay" />'),
    $list;

$first.before($overlay);

// build list out of elements
$list = $([ $first.get(0), $overlay.get(0) ]);

// modify the list
$list.css('border', '2px solid green');
```

Is there a way to do make $list directly out of the two jQuery objects? Can you add a jQuery object to another one?

This would also be more interesting if f.i. `$first` would contain more than one elements.

BTW, I know of this possibility, but it's so unsatisfactory. :)

```
$list = $(".first,.pane");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$list = $first.add($overlay);
```

Note that `add()` is non-destructive: it creates a new jQuery object instead of modifying the one it is called on, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This is so simple that I don't know how I could have overlooked it in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$list = $first.add($overlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add elements to the set of matched elements using [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method like:

```
// build list out of elements
$list = $first.add($overlay);
```